# Ajax success function not working in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

My blade view-

```
@foreach ($songs as $song)
     <a href="{{asset('/audio/' . $song->song)}}" download="" >
        <button type="button" class="download" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
           <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download">Download</i>
        </button>
     </a>
 @endforeach
```

My ajax success function does not work. it doesn't show alert. Therefore I cannot update my database. Here is my ajax:

```
$(function() {
  $('.download').click(function(){
 $.ajax({
   url: "/update_download_count",
   type:"POST",
   data: {
     song_id:$(this).attr('data-id')
   },
success: function(data)
                        {
                            alert("ok");        
                        }
  });
});
    });
```

So, Whats wrong with my ajax call? I want to click on link and pass the the id to my controller.

Comment: Are you getting any JS error or Server Error(You can check that in browser console (Ctrl + Shift + i) in Google Chrome???

Comment: I think you might get `CSRF Token mismatch Exception`

Comment: check your error in network tab of developers tools

Comment: You need to add the ajaxSetup for ajax post requests.

Comment: on developer tools status has shown 500, internal server error

Comment: Click on that 500 error request and see the response tab, you may have an error in php.

Comment: show your Controller

Comment: My controller: [code] public function updateDownloadCount(Request $request) {
    $song = Song::find($request->input("song_id"));
    $song->download += 1;
    $song->save();
}[code]

Comment: add this code to your global js file `$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
});`

Comment: Ok, my csrf issue is solved by adding ajaxSetup. but in my controller there is an error: "Creating default object from empty value", where i increment download_count by 1

Comment: maybe your initial `$song->download` value is not 0. You default `$song->download` should be zero initially.

Answer (score 1):

Its clearly Laravel's token mismatch error. You should always add error handler to the ajax functions to be sure to see if any error has occurred. There two ways you can get through this error.

Method 1: (recommended)

Add a csrf token in the header as @kacem mentioned

Method 2: Only when you are making an ajax request from a different domain to the laravel server running on a different domain or IP

Go to `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` and add your POST URLs in the protected variable

```
protected $except = [
    'post-urls-to-exclude-token-check',
    'multiple-urls',
    'or-wild-cards*
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Add a meta-tag to each page (or master layout):
 <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    And add to your javascript-file (or section within the page):

    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });
```

Comment: CSRF issue has been solved. now showing an error on controller:Creating default object from empty value

Comment: You must be arrowing to a NULL object. i.e. something like this $res = NULL ; $res->abc;

Answer (score 0):

try adding a dataType to your ajax call

```
    $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    ...
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(){

                        ..
                    }
                });
```

and return a json object from your controller.

```
return json_encode( $SomeData );
```